# Source code build error (noob error)

Tags: macos

First time wading into coding... well, not actual coding, yet, but trying to build from a GitHub source. This is for macOS 10.12.6 Sierra, and that is the system I'm using to build this.

I've installed the prerequisites listed:

- xcode
- python
- wxpython
- twodict
- gettext
- ffmpeg

all the latest versions.

Following instructions I changed directory to the source code's folder and typed

```
python setup.py install
```

I got this immediately:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 73, in <module>
    from youtube_dl_gui import (
  File "/Users/davec/Downloads/youtube-dl-gui-master/youtube_dl_gui/__init__.py", line 26
    print error
              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(error)?
```

So what did I miss? My first build, and I'm falling on my face. lOl

I haven't edited any of the source files; I'm not yet brave enough for that...

Project is here:

[youtube-dl GUI](https://github.com/MrS0m30n3/youtube-dl-gui)

Thanks.

Comment: Wow! Ambitious starter project, but you gave great details so I’m hopeful someone can advice next steps to keep the learning going.

Answer (score 3):

It is a python2 source. You are 'building' it with python3. macOS comes with python2.

You can try these shell commands.

```sh
# Verify the version of python in $PATH
python --version

# Use stock python
/usr/bin/python setup.py install
# Or
python2.7 setup.py install
```

Comment: I guess it's a beginner's error to think that new versions of compiler/interpreters are backward compatible....

Indeed Python is version 3.6.8.   I installed a version 2.7 but after installing I see that it's 2.7.15, not the required 2.7.3.

Tried your suggestions:

Typing:
     `/usr/bin/python setup.py install`
gets this output:
     `No module named wx`

Looking for a python version 2.7.3...

Comment: 2.7.15 should be ok it is just bug fixes and additions from 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

It works!!

[image: youtube-dl GUI]

After installing the proper version of Python (2.7.15) and *selecting* it (otherwise it would use version 3 in installed initially), and *re-installing* twodict (for some reason it disappeared), running the command:

```
python setup.py install
```

generated a folder "build" which contains an executable.

Double-click on that and Bob's your Uncle!

Thanks for the input people. I'm confident I can take the next step, whatever that might be. Probably hunt down some more source code and try my hand again at building.

Cheers!